# Conditional Matching Based on Datetime

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of names and datetimes on two sheets.  One sheet we'll call LargerSheet and the other we'll call Sheet1.  On LargerSheet each name has multiple datetimes associated with it.  On Sheet1 each datetime has multiple names associated with it.  The goal is to find out whether the names on Sheet1 have a matching name value on LargerSheet such that the difference between the datetime on the Sheet1 and the datetime associated with the matching name on LargerSheet is less than 72 hours.  The candidate matching datetime on LargerSheet must also satisfy the condition that it is greater than the datetime associated with the name on Sheet1.  To handle the event where multiple datetimes match the criteria the idea is to only look at the first match.  The sample sheet [can be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LBdx3cnA2gkvh7NECJqKuUL4z6hH0SR3ynPMAB1KDl0/edit#gid=0).

Note as well that I have asked similar questions before, but I believe because of the way I worded those questions that they are more confusing than helpful.  Those questions can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/784152/using-index-match-conditionally-to-indicate-whether) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/789177/searching-and-inserting-data-based-on-date-range).

Comment: Line 6 of your sample file seems to fail the criteria 'matching datetime on LargerSheet must also satisfy the condition that it is greater than the datetime associated with the name on Sheet1'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @krowe Thanks for pointing that out, I completely overlooked the time on that entry!  The file has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have come close to answering your question, but it would still need some tweaking.  It uses MS Query to query the workbook from the workbook.  This allows you to run SQL against the sheets and perform much more complex calculations than VLOOKUP.

Now, on to the steps.
1. In the Ribbon, on the Data tab, in the Get External Data section, click “From Other Sources” and select “From Microsoft Query”
[image: Data tab - From other sources - from ms query]
2. Select “Excel Files”
[image: select excel files]
3. In Select Workbook, navigate to your page.  Also change to All Files since they didn’t update the code for the new file extensions.
[image: navigate to your workbook]
4. Next, you select the sheets from which you want to query.  Don’t worry if it gives you an error, as long as you get to the Microsoft Query editor as shown below.
[image]
Now at this point you can start building this query like you would in Access, or you can switch to the SQL view and write the query.  It’s that SQL button in the above image.  The editor sucks, so copy paste to SSMS or N++.  When done, hit the “door exit” button, called “return data”.


For the problem presented, here is the SQL:

```
SELECT `S1`.DATES , `S1`.NAMES , MAX(`LS`.DATES) 
FROM `C:\Admin\StackExchange\vlookup multiple results.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `S1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\Admin\StackExchange\vlookup multiple results.xlsx`.`LargerSheet$` `LS`
ON `S1`.NAMES = `LS`.NAMES
WHERE (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) &gt; -3 and (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) &lt; 3
group by `S1`.DATES, `S1`.NAMES
```

Add the data to a new worksheet to get the following results:
 

[image]
For some reason row 2 doesn’t seem to match the query as it is actually 75 hours awa, but at this point I write that off to some issue with Excel datetime conversion to SQL (MS Query) and back again.

P.S., this answer was also posted to my blog, in case anyone thinks I copied it without attribution.  I just didn't want to get flagged for linking to my own blog.  You can link it if find it.

Comment: That's interesting.  I never thought of using a query.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Unfortunately that query seems to return blank columns.

Comment: @114 The above is a screenshot of it working.  Post your actual query, as it may be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.

For many scenarios you dont need to write a line of code, you just click around in the Power Query UI.  At each step it shows you the result of your data transformation, making for productive testing/debugging.

I've built a prototype solution that you can download and try - its: "Power Query demo - Conditional Matching Based on Datetime intervals.xlsx" in my OneDrive demo folder:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

The FinalResult sheet has my results.

I did have to do one line of coding - the "if" statement for the Matches column in the FirstMatches Query.

Comment: There wasnt any mention of edition limits in the question. FYI you can use Power Query with the Excel Standalone license which costs around USD100 on Amazon. As for putting thought into my answers, on Superuser.com my main contributions are on Power Query and Power Pivot for sure - most people are unaware of those options. I'll leave that discussion there and let my reputation score speak for itself ...

Comment: There is hardly ever version limits (2003, 2007, etc.) in questions, and I have yet to see someone actually post the edition (Pro, Pro Plus).  You should be aware that the basic version of Office, that most corporate and small business users will have, Office Pro, is not compatible with Power Query.