# Microsoft Query in Excel Returning Blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

In [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/803768/conditional-matching-based-on-datetime) I was given a solution that relies on the following SQL:

```
SELECT `S1`.DATES , `S1`.NAMES , MAX(`LS`.DATES) 
FROM `C:LOCATION`.`Sheet1$` `S1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\LOCATION`.`LargerSheet$` `LS`
ON `S1`.NAMES = `LS`.NAMES
WHERE (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) < -3 and (`S1`.DATES - `LS`.DATES) > 3
GROUP BY `S1`.DATES, `S1`.NAMES
```

The goal is to have this SQL pull up dates that fall within a particular range for a given set of names.  The difficulty I am having now is that the query is returning completely blank, despite the query being valid.  Is this something common in Microsoft Query editor or is there some kind of discrepancy between what I'm writing and the result I want?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your where statement says "Give me rows back where both of the following conditions are true: S1 Date is more than three days from than the LS date AND is less than three days from the LS date"

For any given record, both statements can't be true, so you get nothing.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the issue then is that I have the < and > backwards, is that correct?  Then I would get a sensible range.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. I have edited the answer to remove the part about changing the AND to an OR since your desired output is records where S1.Date is within 2 or 3 days of LS.Date.

Comment: Thanks.  Would something like `WHERE (S1.DATES < LS.DATES) and (S1.DATES - LS.DATES) < 3`  work as well?  I think it would give the same result as the above.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Microsoft Query's syntax. I assume it's JET underneath, but even that I'm a little rusty on. The way you have it written will give you back ALL records there S1.DATES is less than LS.DATES, which is probably not what you want. Try `WHERE LS.Dates -3 < S1.Dates AND LS.Dates +3 > S1.Dates` That will give you all records where S1.Dates is within 2 days +/- of L1.Dates.